# SlickGrid drag and drop event issue

Tags: slickgrid

I don't know if this has to do with SlickGrid or with the jquery.event.drop library but my problem is that although my drag from the grid and drop on some element works, I can't get to work the "dropstart" event. I would love to highlight the droppable element when the dragged element touches it.

Comment: Don't know answer to your question. But SlickGrid uses the threedubmedia drag and drop library. http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag In order to get any of the drag and drop events to work you need to add `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` in you subscribed event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the hoverClass property of the droppable element to highlight the droppable as needed? http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#visual-feedback

Maybe post some code here or post a fiddle for more clarity on the issue.